# Passing data from UseEffect to Chart.js not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use the useEffect() hook. I pull data from my API, parse it in useEffect() and store it into temperature using setTemperature(temp). However, when I pass temperature to a chart.js field, it doesn't read in the array. Why is this? I've statically added an array to the chart.js field to test and it works. So I'm pretty sure it doesn't have to do with the chart.js side.

```
const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState([]);
const [humidity, setHumidity] = useState([]);
const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = useState([]);   

useEffect(function() {
    async function getData() {
        try{
            let response = await axios.get('/api/sensorData');

            let temp = [];
            let hum = [];
            let time = [];

            response.data.query.forEach((item)=>{
                Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, val]) => {
                    if (key === 'humidity'){
                        hum.push(val);
                    }else if (key === 'temperature'){
                        temp.push(val);
                    }else{
                        time.push(val);
                    }
                });
            });

            console.log(temp)

            setTemperature(temp);
            setHumidity(hum);
            setTimestamp(time);


        }catch(error){
            console.log('error', error);
        }
    }
    getData();
}, []);

return(
    <div className="container">
        <h2> Environmental Stats </h2> 

        <br/>

        <h3> Temperature </h3> 
        <LineChart 
            labels={['January', 'February', 'March',
         'April', 'May','June']}
            datasets={[
                {
                    label: 'Temperature',
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0.5,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
                    borderWidth: 1.5,
                    data: temperature
                }
            ]}
         />
);
```

Comment: you are setting the async data so you need to wait for sometime and for that you need to set loading flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

**Problem**

you are calling API and its async operation that's why you need to wait for some time to load that function and that's why you need one loading flag to check async function calling finished or not

```
const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState([]);
const [humidity, setHumidity] = useState([]);
const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = useState([]);   
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); 

useEffect(function() {
    async function getData() {
        try{
            let response = await axios.get('/api/sensorData');

            let temp = [];
            let hum = [];
            let time = [];

            response.data.query.forEach((item)=>{
                Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, val]) => {
                    if (key === 'humidity'){
                        hum.push(val);
                    }else if (key === 'temperature'){
                        temp.push(val);
                    }else{
                        time.push(val);
                    }
                });
            });

            console.log(temp)

            setTemperature(temp);
            setHumidity(hum);
            setTimestamp(time);
            setLoading(false);


        }catch(error){
            console.log('error', error);
        }
    }
    getData();
}, []);

if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>

return(
    <div className="container">
        <h2> Environmental Stats </h2> 

        <br/>

        <h3> Temperature </h3> 
        <LineChart 
            labels={['January', 'February', 'March',
         'April', 'May','June']}
            datasets={[
                {
                    label: 'Temperature',
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0.5,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
                    borderWidth: 1.5,
                    data: temperature
                }
            ]}
         />
);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. I'll accept answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of DOM rendering in react the chart most wait until data is fetched the solution is to add a loading... state.

my code
`

```
     const [assets, setAssets] = useState({});
     const [chartData, setChartData] = useState();
     const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/user/content/${#####}`)
        .then((res)=> res.json())
        .then(({content, assets}) => {
              setAssets(assets)
              setLoading(false)
     })
      .catch(err => err);
       setChartData({
               labels: ['income', 'expens'], 
               datasets: [{data: [assets.income, assets.expens]} ]
       })
   }, []);
 return (
  <div className="App">
   <div className="chart-container">
    <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Pie Chart</h2>
    { loading ? (<h1>loading...</h1>):(
      <>
        <Pie
            data={chartData}
            options={{ 
                      plugins: { title: 
                      { display: true, text: "message" }}
                     }}
         />
       </>
      )
     }
    </div>
  </div>
  );
`
```